# using sympy solver and numpy dot doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to solve a long equation using sympy solve. This is a simplified version of the equation but the issue is the same.

This code works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

coupons     = [0.504452818664, 0.486892427806, 0.47758800215, 100.468050176]       
rate = sy.Symbol('rate')
rate_final    = (sy.solve(100 - (rate*coupons[0]+rate*coupons[1]+rate*coupons[2]+rate*coupons[3]),rate)) 

print rate_final
```

`rate-final` is `[0.980998226948197]`.

But when Ι try to use `numpy.dot` inside the equation, it gives an empty list as a result.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

coupons     = [0.504452818664, 0.486892427806, 0.47758800215, 100.468050176]           

rate = sy.Symbol('rate')
rate_final    = (sy.solve(100 - np.dot(rate,coupons[:]),rate)) 
print rate_final
```

`rate_final` is `[]`.

Is there something wrong with my code or `sympy.solve` won't work if `np.dot()` is inside the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dot product of scalar `rate` and vector `coupons` hardly makes sense. You only get an element-wise multiplication of `rate` and each element. However, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

coupons = np.array([0.504452818664, 0.486892427806, 0.47758800215, 100.468050176])

rate = sy.Symbol('rate')
rate_final = sy.solve(100 - np.sum(rate * coupons), rate)
print(rate_final)
```

Comment: so unless the arguments of `np.dot` are _both_ vector like it just does multiplication?

Comment: Yes. For example: `np.dot(2, [1, 2, 3])` -> [2, 4, 6]

Comment: ah yes, just looked at `help(np.dot)` and that is stated in the `Returns` section.  Thank you for clearing this up for me as well as the asker!